# Exit a program using a specific keypress combination?

Tags: c, linux, unix, keyboard, stdin

I am working on a linux machine. I am building a mini command line interpreter. It must terminate when the 'exit' command is received or Crtl-D is input from the keyboard, signaling end of input. How do you exit the program using Crtl-D at any point?

Comment: okay so , crtl-d is an EOF so just iterate until EOF?

Comment: No no no. `stdin` is not a real file, it is a pseudo file. ctrl + d flushes immediately (without need to hit enter). So if your `read` was blocked, it returns immediately with 0 byte read which is termed as EOF here.